# plupload error when uploading files

Tags: javascript, plupload, multiple-file-upload

I am using this Plupload solution to upload multiple files at once, but it gives me this error in browser's conosle `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied`

The code stops here `new n.DOMException(n.DOMException.INVALID_STATE_ERR)` in the `plupload.full.min.js`

What can cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my fault. the path was `file:///.....` instead of `localhost...`